# How to display which user created the post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to learn ruby on rails by creating a reddit clone.

So now I'm trying display the username of the user who created the post, but I'm only getting it displayed as u/username everywhere.

Also when I try to click on u/username to see if I can get data about user by going to his page, all I'm getting is an error saying:

> undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

This is my partial _list class that displays data about post:

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= link_to post.community.name %> | Posted by <%= link_to post.account.username, profile_path(:username) %> <%= time_ago_in_words post.created_at%> ago. </p> </small>
   <%= link_to  post.title, community_post_path(post.community_id, post) %> 
   <%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %>
<% end %>
```

profile.html.erb just to display username for now:

```
<%= @profile.username %>
```

account.rb:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :communities
  
  validates_presence_of  :username


end
```

public_controller:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @communities = Community.all.limit(5)
        @posts = Post.order(id: :desc).limit(20)
    end

    def profile
        @profile = Account.find_by_username params[:username]
    end
    
end
```

post.rb:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    belongs_to :community
  
    validates_presence_of :title, :body, :account_id, :community_id
end
```

and routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :accounts
  get "u/:username" => "public#profile", as: :profile
  
  resources :communities do
    resources :posts
  end

  root to: "public#index"
end
```

[Full repo here](https://github.com/ifiala/reddit-klon)

Comment: You are giving `:username` as a symbol here for  `profile_path(:username)`  method so that in your controller you can't find any account that matches. You should give the `username` data instead. Like this: `profile_path(post.account.username)`

Comment: I tried that already, but then i get an error saying:

No route matches {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"public", :username=>nil}, missing required keys: [:username]

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried the solution i suggest and it worked. Can you refresh the page and ensure that the when you hover on the profile link of the user you should see at the bottom the link like this: `localhost:3000/u/your_username`

Comment: I can't reload at all, as soon as I try, I get the above mentioned error

Comment: Navigate to root page then try the link again please

Comment: root also doesn't work, same error

Comment: Can you check if your DB has a account with no username?

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thank you!

Comment: @ficalino - If you got the issue resolved do post the issue and the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. #cleanup :)